# undefined symbol: luaopen_LuaXml

Tags: lua, luarocks, luaxml

I had installed luaxml module using luarocks. I had used the luaxml to call in a lua script. But getting an error

Lua script:

```
xml = require("LuaXml");
local xobj = xml.eval('<Cmd Message="Hello"/>');
session:consoleLog("INFO","The message in the XML is "..xobj["Message"].."\n");
```

Error:

```
mod_lua.cpp:203 error loading module 'LuaXml' from file '/usr/local/lib/lua   
/5.2/LuaXML_lib.so': /usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/LuaXML_lib.so: undefined symbol:  
luaopen_LuaXml
stack traceback:
[C]: ?
[C]: in function 'require'
```

I had seen the concept of add libraries to Lua dynamically but i couldn't understand. Can anyone help me out. Briefly so that how to link the core module luaxml with the script. 
Another question how can i test whether the installed module luaxml through luarocks is installed or not.

Comment: Try this with lua 5.1

Comment: Which Lua version are You using? Could You please show output of `ldd your_executable`?

Comment: I had tried but gettting the same mistake

Comment: Lua version 5.2.3. What is ldd can you specify more briefly

Comment: Try `nm -g /usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/LuaXML_lib.so`.

Comment: I had tried the comment which you mentioned i got the following output:                                                                                                                          [root@nareshm 101012-1]# nm -g /usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/LuaXML_lib.so 
         w _Jv_RegisterClasses
00001510 A __bss_start
         w __cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.1.3
         w __gmon_start__
00001510 A _edata
00001518 A _end
000003f8 T _fini
0000028c T _init

Comment: @user3580828 I highly doubt all of that will fit into a comment. Edit it in as code into your answer.

Comment: The question is whether `luaopen_LuaXml` appears in the output of `nm`. Perhaps `LuaXML_lib.so` has been compiled as a C++ library and the symbol `luaopen_LuaXml` got mangled. If so, compile it as a C library.

Comment: @lhf luaopen_LuaXml it hasn't appeared in the output of nm. What should i do please suggest me.

Comment: I had changed the lua version to 5.1. And run the command nm, i got the following result: 00001540 T Tokenizer_delete
00001e70 T Tokenizer_new
00001990 T Tokenizer_next
00000f80 T Xml_encode
00001ec0 T Xml_eval
000022f0 T Xml_load
000013b0 T Xml_registerCode
         w _Jv_RegisterClasses
00003804 A __bss_start
         U __ctype_b_loc@@GLIBC_2.3
         w __cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.1.3
         w __gmon_start__

Answer (score 0):

The output of `nm -g /usr/lib/lua/5.1/LuaXML_lib.so` tells us that this file exports `luaopen_LuaXML_lib`, not `luaopen_LuaXML`, which is what `require("LuaXml")` needs.

Now I don't know why `require("LuaXml")` is opening `/usr/lib/lua/5.1/LuaXML_lib.so`. It should be looking for `LuaXM.so` or `LuaXml.lua`, in this order.

LuaXML works by loading `LuaXml.lua`, which does `require("LuaXML_lib")`. This then will load  `LuaXML_lib.so`.

Perhaps there is a mistake in your `LUA_CPATH` or `package.cpath`.

Comment: Where to find the LUA_PATH or package.cpath